# 'app-line' is not a know element in Angular, already declard in @NgModule and exports it

Tags: angular

I don't know why I receive this error in Angular 10:

> ```
> 1. If 'app-line' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'app-line' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
> ```
>
> to suppress this message.

I add this  in the .html view of one component.

```
2 <app-line [data]="lines"></app-line>
```

in the shared.module.ts i already export it:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   ..
    LineComponent,

export: [
LineComponent
```

So actually when I use decorator  should works in other modules as well.

I use  to display div contents in other component.ts. Actually it should works.

Comment: is shared module imported in the module where the parent component is declared?

Comment: do you mean app.module.ts?

Comment: i mean the module where the component where you added `<app-line></app-line>` is declared. As i don't know your project, i can't assume this is AppModule.

Comment: Does it work, if you add the LineComponent to the app.module.ts?

Comment: no it doesn't work, if I put it into the declarations of the app.module.ts